Ansible find output
I want to controll, that only files are linked in a directory. I Link files basend on a variable, content:
TASK [icinga2 : debug] 
ok: [ansible-role-development] => {
    "icinga_features": [
        "checker",
        "mainlog",
        "notification"
    ]
}

After this is use find to register which files are in the directory. I added one file by hand for testing.
- name: Recursively find /tmp files older than 2 days
  ansible.builtin.find:
    paths: "{{ icinga_basedir }}/features-enabled/"
    file_type: link
  register: __features

The files have the extension .conf in the directory, when I link them I add them, so its checker.conf or mainlog.conf. To make it comparable to the icinga_features list I use the regex_replace filter, but it does nothing. Task dont fail and says its all ok although gelf.conf is not in the list
- name: features | Disable features
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ icinga_basedir }}/features-enabled/{{ item }}.conf"
    state: absent
  with_items: 
    - "{{ __features.files }}"
  when: item|regex_replace('^(.*)\\.conf$', '\\1') not in icinga_features

Can someone please clarify where I'm wrong here...

I Found a solution by filtering the output of find:
- name: features | Gather enabled features to compare against icinga_features variable
  ansible.builtin.find:
    paths: "{{ icinga_basedir }}/features-enabled/"
    file_type: link
  register: __features

- name: features | Extract feature names
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    linked_features: "{{ __features.files | map(attribute='path') | map('basename') | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)\\.conf$', '\\1') | list }}"

- name: features | Disable features not activated via ansible
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ icinga_basedir }}/features-enabled/{{ item }}.conf"
    state: absent
  with_items: 
    - "{{ linked_features }}"
  notify:
    - Icinga configcheck
    - Restart icinga
  when: item not in icinga_features

